# Python/Numpy: Setting values to index ranges

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Using Numpy, I can create a 5-dimensional array like this:

```
>>> faces = numpy.zeros((3, 3, 3, 6, 3))
```

I want `(all indexes, all indexes, 0, 4)` to be set to `(1., 1., 1.)`.  Is this possible by only using Numpy (no Python loops)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Both of the following will do it:

```
faces[:,:,0,4] = 1

faces[:,:,0,4] = (1, 1, 1)
```

The first uses the fact that all three values are the same by having NumPy broadcast the 1 to the correct dimensions.

The second is a little bit more general in that you can assign different values to the three elements.

Comment: Is there a way I can put the slice notation in a tuple to pass to Numpy somehow?

Comment: @Synthead, You can use `slice(None), slice(None), 0, 4`

Answer (score 2):

Numpy [slice notation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html) supports doing this directly

```
f[:,:,0,4] = 1.0
```