# How to set first N elements of array to zero?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a long array:

```
x= ([2, 5, 4, 7, ...])
```

for which I need to set the first `N` elements to `0`. So for `N = 2`, the desired output would be:

```
x = ([0, 0, 4, 7, ...])
```

Is there an easy way to do this in Python? Some `numpy` function?

Comment: How about `x[:N] = 0`, if it's actually a `numpy` array?

Comment: Indexing and assigning is covered pretty thoroughly in NumPy's [documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.indexing.html).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python/Numpy: Setting values to index ranges](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20812787/python-numpy-setting-values-to-index-ranges)

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Pure python:

```
x[:n] = [0] * n
```

with numpy:

```
y = numpy.array(x)
y[:n] = 0
```

also note that `x[:n] = 0` does **not** work if `x` is a python list (instead of a numpy array).

It is also a bad idea to use `[{some object here}] * n` for anything mutable, because the list will not contain n different objects but n references to the same object:

```
>>> a = [[],[],[],[]]
>>> a[0:2] = [["a"]] * 2
>>> a
[['a'], ['a'], [], []]
>>> a[0].append("b")
>>> a
[['a', 'b'], ['a', 'b'], [], []]
```

Comment: Note that `0` is the default `start`, and is therefore redundant.

Comment: I guess leaving out the first index looks better.

Comment: Well I guess it's a matter of taste. I think `a[0:n]` is more symmetric and "easier" to generalize to `a[x:y]`, but it's probably "more pythonic" to use `a[:n]`.

Comment: Thanks for [0]*n, this is awesome.

Answer (score 5):

Just set them explicitly:

```
x[0:2] = 0
```

Comment: you will get a typeerror you can assign only lists to lists. (this is for normal lists in python, dont know about numpy)

Comment: And we are talking about numpy here. This works, I checked it in a console.

Comment: @bindingofisaac, it's part of Numpy's magic to make vector arithmetic easier.

Comment: np_reshaped[0:100] = 32001 sets the first 100 rows to 32001 but I want to set the first 100 columns to 32001, thoughts?

Comment: `np_reshaped.transpose()[0:100] = 32001` or `np_reshaped.T[0:100] = 32001` should switch axes