# Pythonic way to update a subset of a list with the same value

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I am doing this:

```
for f in range(n, n + k + 1):
     
     mylist[f] = 0
```

Wondering if I could do something like:

```
mylist[f:f+k] = 0
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to set first N elements of array to zero?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31049544/how-to-set-first-n-elements-of-array-to-zero)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can perform the similar operation but via using list object on the right. For example:

```
my_list = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
f, k = 2, 3

my_list[f:f+k] = [0]*k
#                 ^ List of size "k" i.e. 3

# Updated value of "my_list":
# [1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
```

In the above example, `k` number of elements from the `f`th index in `my_list` will be replaced with the corresponding values from the list on the right.

Please refer [How assignment works with Python list slice?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10623302/2063361) for more details regarding how it works.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is called [slice assignment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10623383/4518341). You just need an object on the right-hand side containing *k* items.

Instead of making a temporary list like in [Moinuddin's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65553717/4518341), you could use an iterator. I believe this will be more efficient for large *k*. Here are two options:

#### [Generator expression](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-generator-expression)

```
mylist = [100, 101, 102, 103, 104, 105]
f = 2
k = 3

mylist[f:f+k] = ('a' for _ in range(k))
print(mylist)  # -> [100, 101, 'a', 'a', 'a', 105]
```

#### [`itertools.repeat()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.repeat)

```
from itertools import repeat

mylist[f:f+k] = repeat('b', k)
print(mylist)  # -> [100, 101, 'b', 'b', 'b', 105]
```